# How can I get a very "blurred" box-shadow out of only the bottom of the box?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to do [this](http://pachonk.com/alex/test/real/pachonkadmin.html) with pure css.

I am trying to make my box shadow with a very big shadow blur like this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0px 200px -2px #888;
```

Below the box, it looks awesome, but above now it's darkening the entire page. How can I make a super big blur without this darkening?

Comment: Why not use a gradient background?

Comment: agreed - it doesn't appear to be a shadow you want now I looked at the link (was the link there before i answered?). If you really insist on using a shadow you'll have to use nested elements and mess around with overflows

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](http://css3generator.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this might be, to use [css-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/gradient) instead of shadows.

I have done a little demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjgps/1/). I am not sure this is what you are looking for though. Here is the css I used:

```
background: rgb(254,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 69%, rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(69%,rgba(254,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(226,226,226,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 69%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 69%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 69%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 69%,rgba(226,226,226,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffff', endColorstr='#e2e2e2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9
```

As generated by [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) tool

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this using [this CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -350px 200px -250px rgba(5, 5, 5, 1);

        box-shadow: inset 0px -350px 200px -250px rgba(5, 5, 5, 1);
```

This is a very cross-browser friendly method and if you apply a background color it will achieve what I believe is your desired result.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjgps/4/)

**Source(s)**

[CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)

Comment: absolutely offtopic ... didn't know the kbd element. You always learn something :-)